# slimslider.js - Having trouble getting plug-in to work in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

For some reason the following code will not work in IE. I've tried using F12 Dev Tools, but it looks like there are no errors. Any help is appreciated. You can also refer to this: http://codepen.io/sanelaxm/pen/cHzdm
Here's the code:

```
/** 
 * Slimslider v1.1.0
 * @author Kyle Foster
 * MIT license
 */
;(function ( $, window, document, undefined ) {

  $.fn.slimSlider = function ( options ) {

    options = $.extend( {}, $.fn.slimSlider.options, options );

    return this.each(function () {        

      // Define our variables
      var counter  = 0,
          element  = $(this),
          wrapper  = element.children('.slides'),
          slide    = wrapper.children('li'),
          slideCnt = slide.length,
          navLink2 = element.find('.slide-nav').find('div').find('a'),
          navLink  = element.find('.slide-nav').find('li').find('a'),
          prefix   = (/mozilla/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()) && 
                     !/webkit/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase())) ? '-moz-' : 
                     (/webkit/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase())) ? '-webkit-' :
                     (/msie/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()))   ? '-ms-' :
                     (/opera/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()))  ? '-o-' : '';

      // Add active class to first nav link
      navLink.first().addClass('active');    
      navLink2.first().addClass('active');    

      // Auto play function (if selected options)
      if ( options.autoPlay === true ) {          

        // Define slideshow variable
        var slideShow;

        // Define play function
        function play() {

          // Don't execute after click function  
          if ( !wrapper.is('.stopped') ) {

            // Slideshow function
            slideShow = setTimeout(function() {

              // Slideshow iterator
              if (counter < slideCnt - 1) { counter++; } 
              else { counter = 0; };  

              // Stop browser 'catch up' when switching tabs
              wrapper.stop(true,true);

              // Fire animation function
              animate();

              // Loop our slideshow
              play();
            }, options.autoDelay );
          };
        };

        // Instantiate our play function
        play();

        // Define our pause function
        function pause() { clearTimeout(slideShow); };

        // Pause on hover (if selected)
        if ( options.hoverPause === true ) {
          wrapper.on({
            mouseenter: function() { pause(); }, 
            mouseleave: function() { play(); }
          });
        };
      }; 

      // Navigation click function
      navLink.on('click', function(e) {

        // Stop auto play (if instantiated)
        //pause();

        // Add a class to keep animation stopped
        //wrapper.addClass('stopped');

        // Set counter to new slide position
        counter = $(this).parent().index();

        // Fire animation function
        animate();

        // Prevent default click action
        e.preventDefault();
      });   

        navLink2.on('click', function(e) {

        // Stop auto play (if instantiated)
        //pause();

        // Add a class to keep animation stopped
        //wrapper.addClass('stopped');

        // Set counter to new slide position
        counter = $(this).parent().index();

        // Fire animation function
        animate();

        // Prevent default click action
        e.preventDefault();
      });   
      // Define our animation function
      function animate() {

        // Iterate through our navigation links
        navLink.each(function() {

          // Cache 'this'
          var currentLink = $(this);          

          // Move to counter's position
          if ( counter === currentLink.parent().index() ) {
            navLink.removeClass('active'); // Clear 'active' class
            currentLink.addClass('active'); // And add to selected link
          }
        });

        // Iterate through our navigation links
        navLink2.each(function() {

          // Cache 'this'
          var currentLink = $(this);          

          // Move to counter's position
          if ( counter === currentLink.parent().index() ) {
            navLink2.removeClass('active'); // Clear 'active' class
            currentLink.addClass('active'); // And add to selected link
          }
        });

        // Animation
        wrapper
          .css( prefix + 'transition' , prefix + 'transform ' + options.animSpeed ) // Apply transition
          .css( prefix + 'transform' , 'translate(-' + counter * element.width() + 'px, 0)' ) // Animate
          .bind('transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd', function() { 
            wrapper.css( prefix + 'transition' , 'none' ); // Kill transition once animation completes
          });
      }; 

      // Define debulked onresize handler
      function on_resize(c, t) { onresize = function() { clearTimeout(t); t = setTimeout(c, 100) }; return c }; 

      // Instantiate resize function      
      on_resize(function() {

        // Cache our slider width
        var newWidth = element.width();        

        // Set wrapper width & reposition
        wrapper
          .css({ 'width' : newWidth * slideCnt })
          .css( prefix + 'transform' , 'translate(-' + counter * newWidth + 'px, 0)' );        

        // Set slide width
        slide.css({ 'width' : newWidth }); 
      })


();    
    });
  };

  // Overridable default options
  $.fn.slimSlider.options = {
    animSpeed  : '0', // animation speed
    autoPlay   : false,   // auto play option
    autoDelay  : 4000,   // auto play duration
    hoverPause : true    // auto play pause on hover      
  };

})( jQuery, window, document );

// Instantiate Slimslider
$('.slider').slimSlider();
```

Comment: What version of IE? I'd suggest adding log statements (or breakpoints, if the dev tools allow) throughout to see where it gets stuck.

Comment: I've tested on 10 & 11 and it doesn't work. I tried using break points, but could not pinpoint what was wrong. For instance, if I clicked a link that should respond to "onclick", the js would not respond.

Comment: It's glitchy at best on android chrome. Does it work correctly in any browser? You sure its not your markup

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure. I'll probably end up going a different route.